# Sudden improvement in running heart rate - is this possible or what happened?

Tags: running, heart-rate, heart-rate-monitor

Background: I have been jogging/running for the last 6 years, on and off, about 1 - 10 times a month. My typical speed allows me 10-minute miles, sometimes only 11-minute miles; my BMI is 30-ε, age 56.

I measured my max heart rate (by running 3 miles and then speeding up until I drop dead), it is 186. My resting heart rate is 45 (it goes regularly to 35 when sleeping, but I guess that doesn't count).

When I run, my heart rate is normally just above 160, and I target to keep it above 155 and below 172. I use two different devices to measure it (Scoche Rythm+ and Fitbit Inspire HR), and they normally match well (I often ran with both, to compare them).

Recently, from one day to the other, this pattern changed significantly - I run the same speed, the same route, the same time of day, but *my heart rate sits now in the 130ies*, for at least two miles (then it goes slowly up). It also *feels* easy, and the natural assumption would be I got fitter, but I doubt that - the jump literally happened overnight, from Saturday (in the 160ies) to Sunday (in the 130ies). Again, both devices agree, and I borrowed a third device to be sure - it is *not* a measuring error.

I can still get the heart rate in the 160ies right away, by sprinting the first half mile, and then it stays up, but unless I do that, I now run 10 and even 9-minute miles in the 130ies (since about six weeks).

**Question: is such a jump overnight possible? If not, what else could it be?**
I'd be happy to accept that I got suddenly fitter, but I find it hard to believe still.

Comment: Any other lifestyle changes? Better diet? Less stressful job? Sleeping longer/better? Did you come back to running after a long break?

Comment: no, none if those. really no root cause I can see.

Answer (score -1):

> is such a jump overnight possible? If not, what else could it be?

Yes, it happened to me to. Going from being exhausted in a 5 minutes run to being able to run 33 minutes. I don't know how to explain it. I speculate that it is due because we are humans, the fittest creature on the planet so far, it is probably normal for us to advance so fast.